# Authenticate in LDAP

Tags: c#, .net

I need to make an LDAP authentication, Im using the follow code:

```
try
        {
            var ldapConnection = new LdapConnection(new LdapDirectoryIdentifier((string)null, false, false));
            var networkCredential = new NetworkCredential(userName, password, domain);

            ldapConnection.Credential = networkCredential;
            ldapConnection.AuthType = AuthType.Negotiate;
            ldapConnection.Bind(networkCredential);
            Console.WriteLine("Ok");
        }
        catch (LdapException ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
        }
```

With my username in my machine works fine but with an user that is located in another machines it does not works and throws me an excetion that says: **Invalid cretentials.**

Whyt it does not works with the other user and works fine on only with my user ? What I have to change in LDAP configuration ?? Thanks !!

Comment: Did u try with your credentials in their machines?

Comment: what do you mean by 'an user that is located in another machines'? The user name and password you give must be a valid user name and password for a user in the domain that machine running this code is joined to

Comment: @Trey Is not duplicate

Comment: @NaveenKN Yes, I have tried and in their machines does not leave me authenticate ... The method just only leaves authenticate an user in them machine

Comment: @pm100 The LDAP configuration only leaves authenticate an user in his machine not in other machine ... If I locate in other machine and try this code with my credentials will not leave me authenticate, but leaves authenticate the machine owner ...